# How to securely rewrote from private directory to index.php with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule in place:

```
############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

        RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

I have a directory called "app" that throws apache's default forbidden access error when access is attempted.

In my PHP app I have a route that I want directed to my index.php - `app/help`. If I use `index.php/app/help` the route will load because I am sending it through index.php directly. If I try remove index.php and call the route `app/help` I get a forbidden access error because my rules indicate that the directory should not be accessed.

How do I have apache securely make my "fake path" available while still blocking the contents of my app directory?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite rules are evaluated top to bottom. So all you need to do is insert the rewrite rule that will redirect `/app/help` *before* the server comes across any rule that would forbid access to that path:

```
RewriteRule ^app/help   index.php [END]
```

The `[END]` tells the server to stop all rewriting. Basically `index.php` is the final destination.  If you have a really old version of Apache, you could use the `[L]` flag instead which isn't as final, but it will work unless you have another rule redirecting `index.php` to yet another path.